# World Cloud with two-word terms?

Tags: r, data-analysis, text-mining, word-cloud, corpus

I am trying to create a wordcloud for my internship and I'm struggling with it, i would appreciate any help!

I have a repository of 200 pdf documents, and I have to build a wordcloud of the terms that are repeated the most. For that, I build a corpus, turn it into a tdm, and use the command wordcloud. The clouds only show single words ("country", "fiscal", "debt", etc.) and I would like to add terms with several words that I have seen frequently repeated in the papers ("fiscal rules", "stability and growth pact", etc.). Because the term document matrix only counts how often a single word is repeated, I would need to find a way to count how many times these "blocks" or "tokens" show up in the text, but I can't find a way to do it from the corpus or group of pdfs. ¿Would anyone know a way to do this? I have tried "tokenizing" or building a dictionary, but it doesn't seem to work when it comes to counting their frequency.

I am attaching the code of how I have been building the wordclouds, and how I attempted to count double words.

Thank you so much in advance!

This is how I got the cloud

```
files = list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
files
Excel_Metadata <- read_excel("Y:/Excel.xlsx", 
                             range = "A1:D203")
View(Excel_Metadata)
corp = Corpus(URISource(Excel_Metadata$files),
              readerControl=list(reader=readPDF))
files.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp, 
                                   control = 
                                     list(removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                          stopwords = TRUE,
                                          tolower = TRUE,
                                          stemming = TRUE,
                                          removeNumbers = TRUE)) 

inspect(files.tdm)

matrixfiles <- as.matrix(files.tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(matrixfiles),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word= names(v), freq=v)

set.seed(6984)

pdf("folder/cloud.pdf")
wordcloud(words= d$word, freq=d$freq, scale= , min.freq= 30, max.words=150, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Paired"), family="serif")
dev.off()
```

This is what I have been trying to get the two-word terms

```
text_tokens("files.tdm", text_filter(combine("fiscal rules")))
inspect(files.tdm)
install.packages("tidytext")
library(tidytext)
filesver = tidy(corp)
token = text_tokens(filesver$text, text_filter(combine("fiscal rules")))

matrixfiles <- as.matrix(files.tdm)
v <- sort(rowSums(matrixfiles),decreasing=TRUE)
d <- data.frame(word= names(v), freq=v)

wordcloud(words= d$word, freq=d$freq, scale= , min.freq= 10, max.words=150, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Paired"), family="serif")
```

Comment: Hello und welcome. Can you please create a minimal example with test data? You code is too complex and the data is not provided. This makes it hard to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I cannot upload my 200 pdf documents but it should work with just one: https://economy-finance.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-11/com_2022_583_1_en.pdf          If you create an excel, and in cell A1 write the name under which you save the pdf (ending with .pdf),  and name it Excel.xlsx, you can just run the code as I posted it (adapting the working directory) and it will work. Thank you so much again!!